# Can't connect Rails and Go via websocket using AnyCable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, go, websocket

I am trying to configure Anycable in a Rails 5.2 application which needs to communicate with a GO server.

This is my anycable configuration in the Rails:

```
default: &default
rpc_host: "localhost:50051"
log_grpc: false
log_file: nil
debug: false # Shortcut to enable GRPC logging and debug level
log_level: info
redis_channel: "__anycable__" 
redis_sentinels: []


production:
  <<: *default
  redis_url: "redis://localhost:6379/1"

development:
  <<: *default
  redis_url: "redis://localhost:6379/2"
```

And the anycable server runs in localhost:3334 (Using default settings.) 
However when I try to connect to the same server  from the GO application I am starting to get connection timeout errors from the Rails side. (Tried vice versa and got timeout on the GO side)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to configure `anycable-go` from your Rails application [anycable-go config docs](https://docs.anycable.io/#/anycable-go/getting_started?id=configuration-parameters). Your Rails app will only be coupled to the AnyCable RPC server. I might be able to write an answer if you can provide information on how you're starting `anycable-go` and with what arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I have my next file:

**config/anycable.yml**

```
development:
  # gRPC server host
  rpc_host: "localhost:50051"
  # Redis URL (for broadcasting)
  redis_url: "redis://localhost:6379/2"
  # You can also turn on access logging
  access_logs_disabled: false
  debug: true
```

and I run my servers:

**my file Procfile.dev** is not neccessary

```
web: bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000
rpc: bundle exec ./bin/anycable
go: sleep 5 && ./cable/anycable-go-0.5.4 -addr 'host.lvh.me:8080' -disconnect_rate=1
```